# LastFM API login - CORS Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I am trying to use the lastFM API. I have started with a very basic template where all i wanted to do was connect to the LastFM API and authenticate myself. I have a button on my HTML page -

```
<button id="auth">AUTHENTICATE</button>
```

Here's the jQuery function to handle the click event -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#auth").click(function() {
                console.log("authenticate called");
                var myUrl = "http://www.last.fm/api/auth/?api_key=32*************8a*****2";
                /*$.get(url,function(data) {
                    alert("data");
                });*/
                $.ajax({

                    // The 'type' property sets the HTTP method.
                    // A value of 'PUT' or 'DELETE' will trigger a preflight request.
                    type: 'GET',

                    // The URL to make the request to.
                    url: myUrl,


                    xhrFields: {
                        withCredentials: false
                    },
                    crossdomain : true,

                    headers: {
                        // Set any custom headers here.

                    },

                    success: function(data) {
                        // Here's where you handle a successful response.
                    },

                    error: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);

                });
            });
        });
```

I am running this on my localhost. As you can see from the AJAX request, it supports CORS. I can also see CORS header attributes being added to my request headers. But the server needs to respond with the CORS headers too like Access-Control-Allow-Origin. But the response does not contain any such headers.

But lastFM API supports CORS, so shouldn't it be sending these attributes in the response headers? Also, now how can I make use of CORS to authenticate my application?

P.S - I know I can use JSONP, but I want to know if there is any way I can handle this using CORS?

Comment: Do you see any errors on the Console? 
By the way as per http://www.last.fm/api/webauth the user actually needs to grant your application access via last fm (basically you get a session token) before you can start making calls. Did you try logging in the old way and then using CORS for the rest of the calls?

Comment: Yup. I got the api key and then was trying to connect to last fm to authenticate the user. The browser says that it cannot allow calls to different domains. Thats the only error. I am completely new to API calls, I have never tried the old ways like using proxies but I know it can be done.

Comment: I think how it works is, say a user comes to your site and clicks get artist or something. You redirect to last.fm.. api_key=xxxx, which will be a *last.fm* login page and the user logs in. Then the user is shown a page saying last.fm is going to share user's information with application X (your application). The user clicks ok and the site redirects back to your site WITH a session token. Now is when you start your CORS calls (using the session token to get access to the user data). At least that's how I think it works.

Just a quick note that the USER could be you. You still have to login.

Comment: So I have a website that's currently hosted on my local server. I have a button and on clicking that, I am redirected to  last.fm.. api_key=xxxx, but I am never shown that page where it says that its requires me to log in. Instead in Firebug/Console, I see that my request has failed. Should I be trying proxies?

Comment: That's strange - you are redirecting (and not calling, right?). Because simply navigating to http://www.last.fm/api/auth/?api_key=xxxxx opens up the login page (just try it - the only thing that you have to change is the api key)

Comment: I am making an ajax call, not redirecting. I tried that already and it does open up. And the weird thing is that in that, i can see the CORS attributes in the response headers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76443/discussion-between-potatopeelings-and-pratik).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @potatopeelings, I got the answer. What we need was not to call the authentication url, but to redirect it to a seperate page which will ask me to authorize the application to use the lastFM account. I also provided a callback URL which will redirect to my application after I have given the authorization.
So my final URL is like  -

```
myURL = "http://www.last.fm/api/auth/?api_key=XXX&cb=http://localhost:63342"
```

And I removed my AJAX call to do the following -

```
window.location.replace(myUrl);
```